# How to suppress reticulate stdout and stderr code chunk RStudio?

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, knitr, reticulate

Trying to do an essay using RStudio and r-notebooks but with `python`. Thats because I want to use the nice latex integration to generate a pretty PDF as I have for R projects. I found `reticulate` to enable Python code chunks such as:

````
```{python, warning=F, message=F, error=F}
path_to_data = '/data/'
norm_images, norm_labels = load_normal(path_to_data + 'treinamento/NORMAL/')
```
````

However, despite `warning=F, message=F, error=F`, knits to PDF (or html) output still contains:

```
##| 0/1266 [00:00<?, ?it/s]  0%|
```

Which is the progress bar it would show when loading the images. It screws the formatting and makes the page unreadable. Even worse for training calls.

I have tried serveral tricks I've found:

- https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/py_capture_output.html
- https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/911
- https://community.rstudio.com/t/disable-reticulate-message-in-rmarkdown/92792

none did it...